# Handlebars array binding not updating using ember framework

Tags: arrays, binding, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm adding items to an array and displaying them using handlebars. However, changes are not shown after an item is added to the array. How can I fix this?

handlebars code:

```
{{#each person in addNewPersonController.child}}
        {{#if person}}
            {{#view Blocks.TimelinePersonView personBinding=person}}
                <p class="inline pull-left" style="position:relative; top:55px; left:5px;">{{person.firstName}} </p>
                <i class=" icon-cog pull-right" style="position:relative; top:-45px; left:40px;" {{action modifyPerson person target="controllers.modifyPerson"}}></i>
            {{/view}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

controller code:

```
addPerson: function() {
        var people = this.get('content');
        this.propertyWillChange("content");
        people.child.push(Em.Object.create({
            id: people.child.length + 1,
            firstName: this.get("firstName"),
            lastName: this.get("lastName"),
            birthday: new Date(),
            gender: this.get("gender")}));
        this.propertyDidChange("content");
        this.clearFields();
        $("#addPersonPopup").modal("hide");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `people.child.pushObject(...`, and no need to call proprtyDidChange

Comment: That worked!! Thanks!! By the way, how long have you been using Ember?

Comment: Not long, a little in March, then a lot after June

Comment: ember has hooks in pushObject to recognize changes to an array (at least that was how it worked when I responded), whereas it doesn't have hooks in push, so it would have no idea the array had changed if you just use push.